# What transformer I should use for negative ion ionizers

Tags: transformer, coil, winding, static-electricity

If I want to create a device that produces high static electricity fields, such as negative ion generators, what kind of transformer specs I should look for?
I want super huge static electricity, and input voltage of 12-24V (1152/2304W).
*Note that I cannot translate "flyback transformer" into a meaningful word in my language, so I can not find what I need by name.*

---

What I suspect is that it is going to be upgrading - more windings at the secondary coil, although I am not sure in that and I for sure don't know how much more windings at the secondary coil as well as what other specs I must look for.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by (1152/2304W)? - And how high voltage is "*super huge static electricity*"?

Comment: @HarrySvensson The more voltage the better. Well, my batteries are 14.4V/80A (total of x4 batteries), which means I can increase the voltage a lot, with the transformer.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Look at this schematic https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/28/61/63464695702046/0/high-voltage-happiness-make-negative-ion-generator.w1456.jpg Although not very compact, it for some reason uses a lot of voltage multiplers instead of a transformer

Comment: This sounds dangerous. Life threatening dangerous. Like a child playing with a gun. I will never give a child a gun. I will never give someone the means to create high voltages who clearly is inexperienced with it. - My advice for you is to not kill yourself.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Yes well I intend to experience myself doing this. I will wear gloves thanks for being concerned about my life. I study electronics at school, not saying I am the best studier, but I want to do this project. I very well realize it is very dangerous.

Comment: Static Electricity is something generated on an insulator ( cap) and when discharged creates ionization.  To remove dust, they use alternating +/- arcs on needles to deionize air.  Why do you want -ions? and why > 1kW What discharge rate ( f)?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I just want to build static electricity generator to pull dust from distance. So I guess I would need to generate more voltage than current. If so, it is also safer.

Comment: No not really safe.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes, not really save

Comment: Why can't you close a question with an open bounty? That's bullcrap! It is VERY unclear what the OP is asking, not to mention it sounds like it's asking for a recommendation for a specific product or where to find it. This question should be closed.

Comment: Not to mention, how is someone with a reputation of "1" able to post a bounty of 100 points?

Comment: Do not discourage her. She wants to learn just as Faraday , Tesla , and Maxwell did. One has to start being a Test Engineer to truly respect theory and understand the effects of V=LdI/dt and EM forces.  All the answers are in any search engine and "Images" gives a quick overview to direct site. be careful, choose key words wisely.

Comment: @DerStrom8 What do you mean? :) My question clearly is "what characteristics matter when choosing transformer to produce high static electricity" type of question, not recommend me best transformer. Here, I, and many others can learn a lot.

Comment: I already have DC to AC converting/simulating board, next would be the voltage multipliers I might not put yet, then is the questionable transformer. I will as well use Arduino for a little bit of control, but this is OOT.

Comment: @DerStrom8 The answer is that the user didn't start out with 1 reputation, that's the ending reputation after offering the bounty. Posting the bounty immediately takes the bounty reputation as payment. The user started off with 101 reputation due to the site association bonus.

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL. An improperly constructed high voltage generator can start producing `ozone`, which can be harmful to your health.

Comment: Ozone was produced on 30 yr old designed photo copiers by Xerox , et al until they realized it caused headaches etc Now they ramp up the - to + 15 kV voltage to minimize drum charge current and arcing.

Comment: Old cathode TV transformers are good. Car ignition coil is also good. You practically need to build a variation of the Tesla Coil or Van De Graaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like danger, get an old  car ignition coil and plug wire and pulse generate arcs from the transformer coil between needles and compare with flat surfaces using thick rubber insulated  sparkplug resistance (carbon) wire using a small LiPo or SLA battery (3kV/mm vs 1kV/mm approx)

**Make a list of objectives** you wish to learn and test and then record and verify them. Consider Ohm's Law, Ampere's law, Coulombs Law, Gauss's Law or the  4 laws summarized by Maxwell that unify them. examine electrostatic forces separately from magnetic and static vs dynamic.

Then start with a spark plug arc and measure the EMI on your AM radio with orientation antenna effect and size and proximity of loop. You can pulse with 5V on primary using a FET switch and reverse body diode using any Schmitt trigger astable and bias the duty cycle with pull down R to control the energy into the coil or use a short one shot . Then replace spark plug with sharp wire tips insulated across  wood. Then start burning wood (etching)

e.g. sheet metal grounded under 1mm thin wood panel and use sharp screw instead of spark plug on a wooden stick to draw arc thru wood and create patterns and smoke.

When you make the smoke, you can test a "smoke detector" or see if the spark across air changes the smoke flow in a certain direction inside the coil.  Use ground wire poking thru the wood to make a big air coil (2cmx2cm) with the exposed magnet wire to connect the spark between battery, sparkplug wire and coil.  You can tape the wire safely on the end of a short "dry" wood ( clean paint stir stick) if you understand where your safety ground and it is  shared with the spark plug surge current and everything  is connected between battery, ignition coil plug ground and tip.

Then add a bigger L in series like an automotive primary "autotransformer" tapped coil and drive the primary and excite the secondary with high V when released for even more danger. But get new or used resistance spark plug wire that is clean and verify the ohms. and try 12V.

Remember V=LdI/dt and dt is very small with an open contact. Turns ratio is about 1k:1 so even the primary will have HV spikes.

Clean silicon is a better insulator than air but only if clean.

Start with 3Vdc or LiPo battery and test your inductor circuit with just wires and spark plug if you like. Respect that big arcs also have UV and XRays so sparkplug 50k ohm wire limits the current  , EMI and severity like that of an arc welder. But is perfect for experimentation.

I did this once to solve a million dollar risk in a transformer factory putting a spark plug igniting in huge clean mineral oil and discovered that when cut laminate core bundles were added  , about a day later the arc threshold dropped due to diffusion or contamination of silicate particles from edges of transformer steel.

I used twin sparkplug wires to feed pulse and ground return on the end of a clean stick going to a HVdc ramp generator to determine the threshold for a relaxation oscillator effect called PD which is the hidden effect inside insulation much like corona outside in air but a smaller cumulative danger.

[image]

If you read the archived books (Archive.org) of Faraday, Coulomb and Maxwell, you will discover they did experiments like this hundreds of years ago to develop the theory we know today.

Maxwell summarizes all the research that was done with static voltages, currents, inductance, capacitance and resistance.  [This is a good reference book.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=A%20Treatise%20on%20Electricity%20and%20Magnetism%20eBooK&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=SjcwWufgO8GR8QeH2qLoAg)

Faraday’s Experiments ebook is also avail.

Try Sig Gen 20V>auto ignition coil>20kV=>HiV rated diode string (bridge) dc hiV cap.

Comment: So to boil down to the most important, skipping the testing part, I use car ignition coil? I will do this project probably with my teacher (she is electrical engineer), I just want to have some better knowledge and beginning, before involving her.

Comment: But I will for sure experiment and read the book later. Perhaps to make this project in a larger scale..

Comment: It's probably a good idea to first do low voltages and build similar to the 2$ ionizers and later improve. I guess it's true that one hour experimenting might equal to 10 hours reading theory

Comment: And I don't read theory for more than 1 hour anyway.

Comment: then spend 10hrs of duplicating experiments. Dont reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Edenia "I don't read theory for more than 1 hour anyway" is … stupidly arrogant. To put it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer option is kind of lame, and it's not supposed to produce static electricity. Adding more windings to a transformer is difficult to say at least. If your 12-24 volts are a.c. you can add a voltage multiplier after secondary winding like in the link you provided:

[image]

The best choice is to build a Van de Graaff generator. That'll be "super huge static electricity". It's used in particle accelerators. Maybe you can use a tandem configuration, depending on what you want to ionize.

Comment: "The best choice" is kind of subjective. I know the Van de Graaff generator and it is bigger and powers by a motor.  Doesn't seem like I can't achieve similar results within the same sizes.

Comment: @Edenia There is an objective reason why they use Van de Graaff for particle accelerators when they need high voltages. As voltages grow the current doesn't need conductors to travel for example, and the highest possible voltages come from this source. You can't call it subjective under any circumstances. The design depends on your requirements, which you did not provide. Also the final price, you did not state your budget.

Comment: That's true.. but I did specify transformer, right?

Comment: And I told you to get any transformer and connect it to a voltage multiplier like in the link, right? That's what they used back in the CRT days.

Answer (score 0):

Does "television transformer" in your language find any for you?   Also try: anode transformer.   Also look for projects called:  solid-state tesla coil, or transistor tesla coil.

Or, just buy DC-powered negative ion generator, $2usd.  These give high voltage and strong electrostatic effects, but are safe because of low current (microamperes.)  Even a 9V battery will serve, but 12V works better.   Here's the ebay search: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=anion+12v+-car&_sop=15

Most neg-ion generators are based on voltage multipliers (a ladder made from diodes and capacitors.)

Comment: the reason I don't want to buy is because of the time I will have to wait. I might end up waiting 2 months for it to arrive to my country. And no, I don't live in the north.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would not suggest a specific product, but since I've seen so many of these cheap "no name" negative ion generators in recent years, I'll post a link. The fact is that just about any high voltage you generate from any transformer producing more than a few thousand volts will product some negative oxygen ions for you. But as most of these modules are out there for $12 or less, you might want to skip the expensive and bulky transformer this time and and just buy the thing. If you want to learn about negative ions and their affects, and get right into experimenting, it might be the way to go. It will produce 15 KV without generating enough current to kill you (though it will knock you on your butt!). Here's one of many...

http://www.goldmine-elec-products.com/prodinfo.asp?number=C9007

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to create static electricity, you don't need to a transformer. Transformers work to change the current and voltage in flowing electricity; static electricity isn't flowing, so there's no current for the transformer to transform.

If your goal is to create static electricity, you'd create it by building an electrostatic generator like a Van De Graaf generator, which works to generate charge on its electrodes via the triboelectric effect.

Here's a link to the Wikipedia page on them, which includes a detailed explanation of how they work, along with a handy diagram of the components of one, along with some pictures of them being used:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator

Comment: Yes but it's one way to do it without mechanical moving particles and without big metal globe. It is also somehow easier to build. Probably even also more cost-effective.

Comment: Not if your goal is to make *static* electricity, it isn't. Static electricity has no current, by definition. You are familiar with Ohm's Law, V=IR, right? Transformers increase I by decreasing V; if V gets doubled, I gets halved. With static electricity, there is no current (I=0), so a transformer won't do anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would've upvoted if I didn't lack 1 reputation :D But I aimed transformers for various reasons. I ordered 20 kv / 12V DC neg. ion generator. I will measure its amps with a clampmeter and see if they are really that low. If it is okay I might just use it instead of building my own. As 20kv is pretty powerful for 12VDC input.

Answer (score -1):

### WARNING - this answer involves using lethally dangerous equipment and voltages. Death is possible.

Well, you could use a microwave oven transformer. They are used to generate high voltage (several kilovolts) that a magnetron inside a microwave oven needs to operate. But be warned that these are deadly. Unless you limit the output current to a safe level, e.g. with a string of suitable resistors (a single resistor won't do!), it will kill you, and you don't even have to touch a naked wire for that to happen: at high voltages, short air gaps can easily break down. Also, for “static”-like effect, you will likely still have to use a voltage multiplier, albeit a shorter one.

Comment: please don't encourage know-nothings to play with MOTs!

Comment: Hmmm, apparently the words “deadly” and “will kill you” aren't discouragement enough for some people. Oh well.

Comment: @Neil_UK doesn't mean his answer is incorrect or bad. And don't call me know-nothing you have no idea what I know and what I don't know.

Comment: @Edenia My apologies if you thought I meant to imply you knew nothing about anything. My remark was to be taken in the context of a question/answer on the subject of high voltage electricity, and was only intended to imply you knew nothing about high voltage electricity. In addition, people who arrive at this answer through a google search are unlikely to know much about it either.

Comment: @Neil_UK I know something about electricity and EE, I study this. This isn't nothing. And this isn't the only project I initiated. However I admit that, I could be/was wrong about stuff. As for the security.. I will wear special protective gloves and my teacher will probably be next to me, until we secure it at least. I will do it no matter who discourages me.

Comment: The observation about death is irrelevant. If you don't have high current, there is no danger. I'm sure the author won't start to build a coil the size of a building.

Comment: The problem with MOTs, however, is that they are perfectly capable of supplying large currents, and you don't need to build them; they are already there. So extreme caution (and knowledge of high voltage safety practices) is crucial.